# Identifying consecutive declining values in a column from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 278 x 2 data frame, and I want to find the rows that have 2 consecutive declining values in the second column. Here's a snippet:

[image: data frame]

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I've searched how to identify consecutive declining values in a data frame, but so far I've only found questions that pertain to consecutive SAME values, which isn't what I'm looking for. I could iterate over the data frame, but I don't believe that's very efficient.

Also, I'm not asking for someone to show me how to code this problem. I'm simply asking for potential ways I could go about solving this problem on my own because I'm unsure of how to approach the issue.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Hint: Have a look into the `.diff()` and (`.shift()` or `.rolling()`) functions of a Series.  This offers a couple of different approaches.

Comment: @Prune You're misunderstanding what I'm asking. I'm not asking for you to "'show me how to solve this coding problem" because I want to solve the problem on my own. I'm unsure of how I should approach the problem, so I was asking for different ways I could do just that.

Comment: "How to approach" is *usually* too broad.  However, I see that you've called out a specific sticking point.

Comment: @Prune Ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `shift` to create a temporary column with all values shifted up one row.
- Compare the two columns, `"GDP" > "shift"`  This gives you a new
  column of Boolean values.
- Look for consecutive `True` values in this Boolean column.  That identifies two consecutive declining values.